# Wordpress issue: get extra html tags appear when I paste url into facebook page

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, tags

When I paste a friend's wordpress site url in a facebook comment, I see the following extra text (I've changed the url for anonymity) The home page of the wordpress blog is titled "Home"

For some reason facebook adds the extra lines in i.e. where it says *"You may use these HTML tags and ... "* or perhaps the wordpress generated html get incorrectly parsed/referenced in the facebook comments browser.

I have zero wordpress experience but do understand CMS concepts well. Any help on how to resolve this will be much appreciated by my friend. I can disclose the url if its really needed to resolve the issue. I decided to try posting the question with an anonymous url first, just in case this is a known, encountered-before issue.

Wondering if the facebook graph-api has anything to do with this? (FB graph-api is not my forte either as I'm more into iOS development)

```
Home 
http://mywordpressfoo.net/
You may use these HTML tags and attributes: 
<​a href="" title=""> <​abbr title=""> <​acronym title=""> 
<​b> <​blockquote cite=""> <​cite> <​code> <​del datetime=""> 
<​em> <​i> <​q cite=""> <​strike> <​strong>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your friend's blog does not have [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me/) tags. Facebook uses these to determine how URLs display when posted on their site (e.g. YouTube URLs display embedded videos, Flickr URLs photos, etc.).

You can find more information about the metatags that Facebook supports in [their OpenGraph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/objects/). Your friend will probably want to make individual posts "[Articles](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/#article)", while the homepage should be a "[Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/#blog)" or a "[Website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/#website)".

Depending on your friend's competency with editing WordPress templates, they might find it easier to integrate [Facebook's official WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/), which includes support for OpenGraph tags.

Comment: Thank you! Will look into that document. That's probably the key!